# How to cycle through columns in each worksheet of a workbook hiding all but specific columns?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

Salutations all,

I am trying to program a macro for a workbook possessing some arbitrary amount of worksheets. Each worksheet is a semi-formal representation of data: that is to say, creators of these workbooks have not availed themselves to the suite of utilities provided natively by excel i.e. no tables, a non-standard (particular to each person) use of colors, inconsistent population of data into an array of cells that can rough be described as employee versus hours per client.

So this is what I am trying to do:

I want to cycle through each column in each worksheet hiding each column that doesn't possess a particular string value. My working hypothesis is that my code may not be working because multiple cell values (rows and columns) were merged wherein the key string is kept. They all seem to roughly be in row 2 for each column, but not in their entirety. You can find my attempt below. It's a primitive attempt, but I can't think of a better approach. Note that not only does the macro not fulfill its purpose, it only changes the last worksheet by hiding all but one of the columns.

```
Sub hideColumns() 

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim str As String
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            str = Cells(2, currentColumn).Value
            Select Case str
                Case Is = "Employee"
                    Columns(currentColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case Is = "Non Billable"
                    Columns(currentColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case Is = "FTO"
                    Columns(currentColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case Is = "Total"
                    Columns(currentColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case Else
                    Columns(currentColumn).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End Select
        Next
    Next ws
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for any advice that could lead to a resolution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each of your `Columns(currentColumn)...` lines _should_ be `ws.Columns(currentColumn)...` and I think you should also be referencing `ws.UsedRange` rather than `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`; also your `str =` line _should_ be `str = ws.Cells(2, currentColumn).Value`

Comment: Without a screenshot (including row numbers & column headers) showing your headings  I don't think anyone will venture a solution, as it isn't clear _where_ the targeted headings _could_ be if they're not in row 2, or where the merged cells are... (since the action for all 4 of the types of column targeted is the _same_, you could consolidate your `Case` construct, i.e. `Case "Employee", "Non Billable", "FTO", "Total"` and then just have the `Case Else` line)

Comment: It's ok. I got it to work. I just needed to 'tighten the screws' on my string criterion.